# React router hashHistory explained

Tags: react-router, browser-history, shim

Quote from here https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-tutorial/blob/master/lessons/02-rendering-a-route/README.md:

> We're using hashHistory--it manages the routing history with the hash
>   portion of the url. It's got that extra junk to shim some behavior the
>   browser has natively when using real urls. We'll change this to use
>   real urls later and lose the junk, but for now, this works great
>   because it doesn't require any server-side configuration

Can someone please explain what this means ?

Is this something a begginner should understand ? (This seems to be a beginner tutorial.)

Comment: Found this : https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/Histories.md - I hope it explains.

Answer (score 2):

hashhistory simulates a nice url using the hash 
symbol

```
example.com/#/some/path
```

while browserHistory uses History api to create an url like this one:

```
example.com/some/path
```

You can have a reference here: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/Histories.md

Comment: The link is currently broken.

Comment: and what is the meaning of the hash? why is it different?